# Guardar valor de un input en session

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

estoy aprendido a trabajar con Session, quisiera saber si es posible almacenar el valor de un campo input en Session

**Necesito pasar el valor 25 y luego almacenarlo**

```
 <input type="hidden" name="idevento" value="25">
```

Controlador:

```
    session(['variableName' => $request->input("idevento")]);
```

Luego obtengo el valor con:

```
   $valor_almacenado = Session::get('variableName');
```

El problema es que siempre llega Null, porque sucede esto?

Comment: Prueba usando el mismo helper para obtener los datos `session('variableName')`. Tambien revisa tu archivo `config/session.php` para revisar que driver estas utilizando

Comment: ya intente con el helper, el campo input debe estar dentro de un <form>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a guardarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$request->session()->put('variableName', $request->input("idevento"));
```

o

```
session()->put('variableName', $request->input("idevento"));
```

y para recuperarlo:

```
$valor_almacenado = Session::get('variableName');
```

Comment: una pregunta, el input debe estar detro de un <form> para que funcione y guarde el valor del input en session?

Comment: Si envías el input al controlador por el metodo post, si debes incluirlo en un form. Entiendo que es lo que quieres, porque sino no pondrías el input como hidden. Espero te ayude!